# conda.auxlib.exceptions.ValidationError: Value for url cannot be None

Tags: linux, conda, environment

When I installed the environment with the following command:

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

I encountered the following problem:
[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please don't post images of error messages. Always put them in your question as text

Comment: What is your conda version?

Comment: Conda version 4.14.0